# Finding the t-value in order to find the maximum curvature for a space curve.

Tags: vector-spaces, problem-solving, curves

Editted work.

I am attempting to find the maximum curvature for the space curve mentioned below.

space curve: $\vec{r}(t) = <3t, 4t, e^{2t}>$

From the space curve, I'm able to find that:

$\vec{r}' = <3,4,2e^{2t}>$

$|\vec{r}'| = \sqrt{25 + 4e^{4t}}$

$\vec{r}' \times \vec{r}'' = <16e^{2t}, -12e^{2t}, 0>$

$|\vec{r}' \times \vec{r}''| = 20e^{2t}$

By plugging in the above, the general curvature is:

$k = \frac{|\vec{r}' \times \vec{r}''|}{|\vec{r}'|^{3}} = \frac{20e^{2t}}{(25+4e^{4t})^{3/2}}$

Find the point of max curvature by:

Setting $\frac{dk(t)}{dt} = 0$ to find critical values.

Without loss of generality, set numerator of quotient rule = 0,

$[(25+4e^{4t})^{3/2}]\frac{d}{dt}(20e^{2t}) - 20e^{2t}\frac{d}{dt}[(25+4e^{4t})^{3/2}]$

Just to keep it simple, let $\Re = 25+4e^{4t}$,

$\Re^{3/2}(40e^{2t}) - 20e^{2t}[\frac{3}{2}\Re^{1/2}\frac{d\Re}{dt}] = 0$

Simplify by taking out the $20e^{2t}$,

$\Re^{3/2}(2e^{2t}) - \frac{3}{2}\Re^{1/2}\frac{d\Re}{dt}$

Simplify by taking out the $\Re^{1/2}$,

$\Re(2e^{2t}) - \frac{3}{2}\frac{d\Re}{dt} = 0$

With $\Re = 25 + 4e^{4t}$ and $\frac{d\Re}{dt} = 16e^{4t}$,

$(25+4e^{4t})(2e^{2t}) - \frac{3}{2}(16e^{4t}) = 0$

$\Rightarrow50e^{2t} + 8e^{6t} - 24e^{4t} = 0$

$\Rightarrow25 + 4e^{4t} - 12e^{2t} = 0$

When subbing in $x = e^{2t}$, I end up with unreal numbers when I try to solve, which cannot be used in my attempt to find max curvature. Can anyone try to point me in the right way or see if I somehow messed up in my calculations. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the curvature formula should be
$$
\kappa = \frac{\lVert r'\times r''\rVert}{\lVert r'\rVert^3}
$$
From your equation you have
$$
r' = (3,4,2\mathrm{e}^{2t})
$$
this leads to
$$
\lVert r'\rVert = \sqrt{3^2 + 4^2 + 4\mathrm{e}^{4t}} = \sqrt{25 + 4\mathrm{e}^{4t}}
$$
This is different to what you have in your equation above.

$$
\lVert r'\times r''\rVert = \left(\matrix{\mathbf{\mathrm{e}_{x}} & \mathbf{\mathrm{e}_{x}} & \mathbf{\mathrm{e}_{x}}\\
3 & 4 & 2\mathrm{e}^{2t} \\
0 & 0 & 4\mathrm{e}^{2t}}\right) = \lVert\left(16\mathrm{e}^{2t}, -12\mathrm{e}^{2t},0\right)\rVert = \sqrt{16^2\mathrm{e}^{4t} + (-12)^2\mathrm{e}^{4t}} = 20\mathrm{e}^{2t}
$$
so you are trying to maximise
$$
\kappa = \frac{20\mathrm{e}^{2t}}{(25 + 4\mathrm{e}^{4t})^{3/2}}
$$
you can proceed like you did above
$$
2\kappa + 20\mathrm{e}^{2t}\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{(25 + 4\mathrm{e}^{4t})^{3/2}} = 2\kappa + 20\mathrm{e}^{2t}\left(-\frac{3}{2}(25 + 4\mathrm{e}^{4t})^{-5/2} \cdot 16\mathrm{e}^{4t}\right)
$$
note I think you did not account for the fact you are working with (using your variable names) $\Re^{3/2}$ as opposed to $\Re^{-3/2}$ which have different properties when taking the derivative.

ultimately we end up with
$$
\dot{\kappa} = 2\kappa -\frac{3}{2}\frac{16\mathrm{e}^{4t}}{25 + 4\mathrm{e}^{4t}}\kappa = 0
$$
so we end up with either $\kappa = 0$ which is trivial
$$
2 -\frac{3}{2}\frac{16\mathrm{e}^{4t}}{25 + 4\mathrm{e}^{4t}} = 0
$$
which ends up as
$$
\mathrm{e}^{4t} = \frac{50}{16} = \frac{25}{8}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for commenting! I wanted to confirm/clarify a few things that are confusing to me. For the ||r'||, when 2e^2t is squared, should't it equal to 4e^4t?    
Also, I tried multiple times, but every single time I am getting 20e^2t for the ||r' x r''||. My vector for r' x r'' = <16e^2t, -12e^2t, 0>.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I will fix the solution. Though if you fix the solution above do you get a realistic solution when solving for $t$?

Comment: @Amai updated to fix the errors raised.

Comment: Im afraid not. I get an unreal again.

Comment: I updated the equations and it seems you only need to take a log of a positive number. See above.

Comment: Hrm can I ask what the 2k is for? I was told to set the numerator portion of the quotient rule equal to zero. My steps in the main post were also updated to reflect the error you mentioned in the beginning.

Comment: I just wanted to factor out the common terms which was the curvature function itself. Then we want to set the factors to zero. $\kappa$ can be zero, but the interested part is the other factor outlined above.

Comment: Why does your 20e^2t suddenly become 20e^4t?

Comment: @Amai it was a typo.

Comment: Yee Im not getting how this works. Might have to try to go to office hours or something. Was trying to avoid that cause I dun wanna stay untill 11pm, but thank you!